# CarPlay: is a now playing "alert" possible?

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

Navigation apps can display a navigation "alert" (I'm not sure how to call it) as shown in this picture.

[image]

Is it possible to show such an alert in an audio app on CarPlay when the app itself is in the background?

Comment: I do't think that possible for an audio app

Comment: Thx ... I read the CarPlay documentation: https://developer.apple.com/carplay/documentation/CarPlay-App-Programming-Guide.pdf and came to the same conclusion, but this "alert" possibility is not mention for navigation apps either. Or do I miss something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think those are special maneuver and navigation alerts just available for navigation apps (which can enable them if running in the background).

Audio apps don't have the ability to show similar alerts. I think there is in theory a way to get messaging apps' notifications to appear (like WhatsApp) if you have a special CarPlay messaging entitlement and your notifications are just text (aka readable by Siri) and work with voice input.

We are also really interested in getting such a functionality in CarPlay but haven't had any success with the current CarPlay framework.